# Vertical space that is ignored at bottom of page or column

Tags: page-breaking, vertical-spacing

How can I get a vertical space that behaves at the end of a page or column like `\vspace{}` does at the beginning of a page, that is, is ignored. And how would I get a vertical space that combines the properties of these two types of vertical space, meaning it would be ignored if it happens to be at the beginning **or** end of a page/column?

I intend to use this for simple paragraph separators, like asterisms or dinkuses, where a vertical space is undesirable if they are at the end of a page. (I know of packages, but do not want to use them because they do stuff I do not need.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
A paragraph

\vspace{6cm}

{\centering\noindent *

}

\vspacebot{6cm}% If this space happens to be
% at the end of a page/column I want it to
% be ignored just like the \vspace above at
% the beginning of a page.

Another paragraph

Just for completeness, it would be nice to
have a vertical space that collapses at
either the top or the bottom.

\vspacetopbot{6cm}

Last paragraph
\end{document}
```

I tried to get the intended effect of a collapsing vertical space by inserting a `\nopagebreak`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
A paragraph

\vspace{6cm}

{\centering\noindent *

}

\vspace{6cm}
\nopagebreak

Another paragraph
\end{document}
```

In this example, the second `\vspace` is glued to the next paragraph in the case of a page break and thus should vanish at the top of the next page and the asterism should sit at the bottom of the previous page. Unfortunately, TeX ignores this and breaks the page at `\nopagebreak`.

---

**EDIT:**
I found something very similar to what I want in *The TeXbook* by Donald E. Knuth. On page 70, he writes: “A plain TeX `\medskip` appears before and after each “dangerous bend” section of this manual …” So there appear vertical spaces (`\vskip`s) before and after these paragraphs, just like before and after my  asterisms. On page 77 we see such a dangerous bend section sitting perfectly at the bottom of the page, without ugly vertical space after it. So it is achievable. How do I do this, if I do not have a dangerous bend section, but a paragraph consisting of a centered asterisk? Both are paragraphs, aren't they?

---

**EDIT 2:**
The linked question is not at all related to my question. It does nothing to help answering my question. I do not want an asterism to disappear at the end of a page. I want the opposite. I want it to stay there. I only want a vertical space at the bottom of a page to be ignored.

Comment: If you use `\vskip 6cm plus 1fil` it will take up at least 6cm and expand to fill the rest of the page if needed.  Note that the page will still end with text.

Comment: You can look at the code of [`needspace`](//ctan.org/pkg/needspace), which checks available space at the end of a page/column. Then you can condition on what you want to do.